# Field definitions changes by PostSharp not friendly to using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

I'm using PostSharp's `LocationInterceptionAspect` to intercept invocations of fields and properties of a class. It is obvious that PostSharp changes such class at compile-time. However, it's getting in my way, and the problem isn't only related to elegance of code that depends on this functionality.

Namely, I also use lambda-expression to obtain the name of those fields and properties. Here's a simplified example, to demonstrate this:

```
    namespace Example
{
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    public class Data
    {
        public string Field;

        public string Property { get; set; }
    }

    public class Process
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            string name1 = this.GetAttributeName<Data>(data => data.Field);
            // name1 = "<Field>k_OriginalField"

            string name2 = this.GetAttributeName<Data>(data => data.Property);
            // name2 = "Property"
        }

        private string GetAttributeName<DECLARING_TYPE>(Expression<Func<DECLARING_TYPE, object>> expression)
        {
            return (expression.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member?.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**It should be obvious: I would like the "<Field>k_OriginalField" to be "Field". Can anything be done here?**

Sure, I could make some assumptions about the format of this string and parse out the value that I want, but that seems a little ugly solution to me. I do need to keep field definitions and obtaining their names as demonstrated, though (their purpose is much more complex than what's visible here). I'm not sure what's even going on internally with .NET's construction of that lambda-expression, since `Data.Field` clearly exists (I verified via disassembling also), but it's been changed into a property, and I guess I'm being handed a backing-field instead, and I'm confused as to why.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I figured out why this happens (I forgot to check earlier): PostSharp also changes usage of this "field" member (but I'm still questioning why), to this:

```
string name1 = this.GetAttributeName<Data>(data => data.<Field>k_OriginalField);
// name1 = "<Field>k_OriginalField"
```

I find this usage-replacement weird because the whole point of PostSharp's intercept-aspects is to redirect the execution flow (while allowing custom execution control), so adjusting invocations to those changes makes no sense to me. Both `Data` and `Process` classes are in the same assembly; perhaps separating them would solve the problem, but I cannot easily do that, and - again - it looks ugly as a solution. I'm hoping PostSharp team will have something to say about this.

Comment: Would be good if you provide full example, together with aspect. Just so that we can just run it and immediatly see the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I uploaded the minimum code that demonstrates this (Visual Studio solution): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YhLAq_mymrTmZrYkdFb25HWEU/view

Comment: Interesting case indeed. It's clear why this happens, but not sure you can do much about this. Why by the way you use public _fields_? Why not properties instead, as recommended?

Comment: I'm creating a custom solution to mapping values between data types (classes), while monitoring which values are set and retrieved on runtime, so that only matching (mapped via such configuration) values on the target type can be set/considered.

Comment: I would expect PostSharp not to adjust existing usage of altered fields within the code that it can reach at compile-time, as that definitely wouldn't happen if the client code lived in another assembly and/or solution. So - unless I'm not seeing the underlying reason - I find that "adjustment" unnecessary, clearly causing a bug here. For now, I decided to parse out the name within my GetAttributeName method, while falling back to what Linq originally delivers.

Comment: But note that to provide interception, PostSharp replaces field with property with the same name. So for that to compile - it has to replace all references to that field in current assembly (because IL to call property getter and get field value are not the same). So it correctly rewrites all usages of that field. Now, it could have replaced that with references to the property instead, and it probably does that, but not in expression trees.

Comment: I understand that the field is changed to a property with public getter and setter and that a backing-field is created. I do not fully understand why referencing code needs to be adjusted to point to the backing field, since the name of the original member (now, the property) and its data-type are still matching, therefore the client code will still compile and execute. Isn't the point of the aspect to actually redirect the execution so that it goes through the newly created property, and not continue to bypass it?

Comment: Remember that postsharp executes only _after_ your assembly is compiled, and it rewrites IL code. So when it changed field to property, it has to rewrite all IL code that referenced this field, because IL instruction to get field value is not the same as getting property value. Now, why it rewrites expression tree to reference old field and not property - that I don't know.

Comment: OK, now I see that there is a reason to this behavior that relates to something that PostSharp cannot control (what you said about IL-referencing). That's something beyond my understanding, so, I'll just drop it, I guess. Perhaps it is a bug on PostSharp's part what you said about expression-tree not getting the same grace. Hopefully this gets noticed by the PostSharp team then. Thank you for your help. I have to stick with public fields, and I'll either move the `Process` class to another assembly or resort to name-parsing within the `GetAttributeName`.

Comment: Maybe PostSharp is not sophisticated enough for that. One thing is just rewrite all calls to field value to calls to property value, and another thing is rewrite whole expression (and all that happens with raw IL code). Maybe PostSharp authors will take note and implement that in future versions.

Comment: Thank you for your time, and that explanation, Evk.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing some hidden complexity here, by why can't you just use the nameof() operator? as in `nameof(Data.Field)`?

Comment: Because I haven't thought of it, that's why! Thank you! I'm adding support for that right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a PostSharp expert, but I don't think this is a decidable problem in the (most) general case.

Think about it. PostSharp rewrites part of the type system of your application at build time, informed by whatever static analysis that it can execute at that moment, for all the relevant assemblies, versions, and namespaces reachable by then.

It cannot see in the future and decide which candidate rewritings ought to be omitted because of client call sites that need to make different assumptions at builds that would occur at a later point in time, and which would look at the your same type system without looking thru PostSharp's lenses, or using different ones.

That is how, I think, it must assume that all the rewritings, that it is instructed to do when it is invoked over your types, must be honored in a type-safe way everywhere they are applicable.

Just my intuition.

'HTH,

Comment: If the calling code lived in another assembly/solution, it wouldn't be subject to such change. I'd think that PostSharp's modifications should/must be made in such a way that interfaces/contracts are not broken. In this particular case, fully public property is fully compatible with the formerly public field: I see no reason why the references to it need to be adjusted. That decision results in different behavior across two pieces of exact same code, relative to their location (assembly-wise).

Comment: In other words, if I moved my `Process` class to a different assembly (and made sure PostSharp cannot modify it, if necessary), then it [the `Process`] would compile and run (and return expected result, too). And, that makes this inconsistent and unnecessary, I'd say.

Comment: @h2015 I get what you say. But see. PS by design chooses to translate a field into a new property with a new backing field, as you found out. My guess is it's to be able to intercept the get and set on a field at runtime later on if necessary. Still, it must honor the fact that your lambda accesses *a field* whether you look at it before or after its rewriting. So, it hands you out the new backing field, because it must preserve the IL reflection semantic. Can be avoided if PS doesn't do ".Field" translation from field to prop, but then you lose the possibility to intercept setting a field.

Comment: Bottom line, is I believe you're hitting the edge of a tradeoff between PS overall functionality and keeping your custom reflection code happy / accommodating enough with PS choices wrt. its AOP implementation... for that functionality. All that being said, the PS authors will hopefully have some guidance for you on how to make that tradeoff work better for you.

Comment: Thanks; I figured out a work-around, but I'll have to accompany it with explanation (e.g. comments/readme-file) to prevent future temptation to rearrange this code (and not realize the consequences until it's too late). I've thought of this problem from multiple angles (usage of public fields is questioned, location of client code, and then some), and I still am [thinking about this]: I'm not ignoring your suggestions; it's just that I'm somewhat stuck with the architecture I'm currently working with (the code-base is huge and very complex), so, I just jump into, e.g. not using public-fields.

Comment: @h2015 Thinking about it, with your last comment, and looking at your code again... we must keep in mind you are passing an expression tree -- PS could be "smarter" and knowing that it decided to rewrite the field "Field" into a prop, it could have gone as far as rewriting that expression tree into one where the new prop is accessed, not the new backing field -- but then... what if your GetAttributeName would pass that tree, to say, a Linq IQueryable extension? That hypothetical IQueryable's provider and its visitor would interpret maybe completely differently this "data => data.Field" ...

Comment: ... to which we could reply: "yeah, but there is no IQueryable to be found in there anyway, so what's the point of being so obsessively conservative about rewriting that "data => data.Field" lambda and keeping the field access in there, instead of leveraging the new AOP-property "Field"? Well, late binding (e.g., a hidden IQueryable disguised as a "System.Object" in your method parameter signature) would screw everything up at run time. The only way I could think (PS feature request?) to handle that would be for PS to allow you to decorate with a custom attribute your "expression" param there.

Comment: ... some meta data attribute that would say, "hey, whatever type members you can find in that Expression<...> that you had to rewrite somehow, it's safe to leverage them -- I don't care if that's not the exact same expression trees compiled in the end, that wrap the predicates I'll throw at it." -- anyway, interesting issue you stumbled upon, if I dare say :) 'HTH,

Comment: Thanks. It's not a huge deal, since work-arounds are found and working. Sure, I ended up adding that special handing that might be confusing to look at, but that's what code-comments are for: I described what's going on for the next guy, and the life goes on. Perhaps PS will enhance this a little in the future, and then that special logic can be removed.